# Dual styling on ASP.NET MVC 4 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, styles

I'm not sure if this is a common query but here goes...

We are developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 website and a requirement has come up to be able to have two sets of styles running at the same time. The idea being that a select few people will get to the see a certain (new) set of styles and the rest will see the current styles.

Ideally, we do not want to have separate pages or a separate website to cater for this. What I'd like to know is what is the best way of going about this? Are there any common practices that should be followed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another layout. They're not special: just partial views like any other partial view, with the exception that they use `@RenderBody()` to include the content from the current view being rendered.

You can then either explicitly specify the layout in your view(s):

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AlternateLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Or you can add/edit a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file to the directory or directories containing views that should be rendered with the alternate layout. That file would just include the code above and nothing else.

Then you can customize it however you like.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this would be the way to go but wasn't sure if there other, more common ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do this is to have two separate CSS style sheets, and swap in one or the other based on whatever criteria determines which group the user is in.

This requires keeping all (or at least most) style declarations out of the markup -- no (minimal) use of the style attribute in your source HTML>